# CSS is not working when I am trying to access a small web app from other computers

Tags: java, css, html, tomcat7

I have developed a small demo web app which is hosted on tomcat. When I access this app from my localhost, everything works fine. But when I try to access it from other computers using my machine's IP, then I am able see the web page but the CSS is not working as expected (the html entities are not at there places).

I am using HTML5 and external style sheets to display the web page.

I tried to find out the solution for this, but didn't find it. I really appreciate help from you guys on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the computers on the same network? And how does the URL that you're trying to access look like?

Comment: Check the css path is correct. CSS path should not start with `http://localhost/...` or `http://127.0.0.1/....` which will not work on another computer.

Comment: thanks guys for replying... computers are on different networks and the url which I am using to access the web app is http://myip:8080/samplewebapp/login.html ..... Yes Muthu, I am using the http://localhost.... path to access css from my web page... could you please tell me how else can I access it form my html page?? Thanks for your replies

Comment: @Mahi : this seems a definite path prob , simply correct the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your CSS path like this, for example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/FOLDER/style.css">
```

Instead of `http://localhost/` use simply `/`

Comment: Thanks Muthu,,, I tried your suggestion and I am able see the beauty of my web app from other machines now...:)... I removed the localhost address and gave folder path for CSS inside the web app directory and it worked... thanks alot...:)